# How can I get Outlook 2016 to remove deleted email from the POP server?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, pop3

I have a domain registered with gandi.net, which also provides an email box, which is used by a relative of mine. He connects to it through POP from Outlook 2016. Even if he deleted messages from his inbox and empties his Deleted Items folder, the email is not removed from the server. I have verified this by accessing his email through the webmail interface provided by gandi.net, SOGo.

These are the Outlook 2016 POP mail settings:

- [✓] Leave a copy of messages on the server

  - [  ] Remove from server after __ days
  - [✓] Remove from server when deleted from Deleted items

Under `Options > Advanced > Outlook start and exit`:

- [✓] Empty Deleted Items folder when exiting Outlook

I have clicked on `Tools > Empty Deleted Items Folder`.

The only folder that contains messages is Inbox (10478).

I have exited Outlook.

In the SOGo webmail interface, I see 18255 messages (i.e., the deleted and purged messages are still on the server). The Trash folder is empty.

**How can the messages be deleted from the server?** I don't mind providing a backup of messages that have not been deleted, but I do not want to keep paying to store deleted emails.

Comment: Agree with Tetsujin and John 's detailed suggestions, please check if they could be helpful to your issue. ISP settings will indeed also influence Outlook behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I use POP email for two of us - two different accounts.

The setting to Delete mail on Exit does work. Our Server mail is deleted when Deleted items are removed.

Your description makes it appear that Outlook is fine. You can always try repairing Office (Control Panel, Programs and Features).

So at this point, register a case with gandi.net  . There may be a setting you need that is otherwise not common. Also, one of our POP accounts requires a special password setup to work properly, so check that. Both the above are the email ISP responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

POP3 email access is "once per device" - this differentiates from IMAP significantly.
POP3 deletion is not triggered by the server, it is triggered by the client.
A POP3 server has no Trash folder - that is only for IMAP.

Once emails are on the client, you can consider the server is done with them - though many will store indefinitely unless specifically triggered (some are actually IMAP behind the scenes which confuses this issue, unfortunately)

The practical upshot of this is that unless you don't have sufficient backup protocol for your computer 'at home' then there is no reason to store anything on the remote POP server once you have downloaded it.

You can therefore simply set your local mail app to delete after a set time period. Saving until deleted locally doesn't actually gain you anything short of 'disaster recovery'.